# cannot connect to the host-name, SSH timeout error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ssh, timeouterror

I am currently using an EC2 Instance where, I try to connect to the instance using the Visual Studio Code using the SSH. But often sometimes I get the error message that **Cannot connect to the <Host-Name, SSH timeout error>**

can anyone help me out to solve this problem and let me know what is going wrong to get that error message.

I tried to stop the instance and re launce the instance and then connect to the instance using Visual Studios. Then it worked. Iam thinking that if the instance get some heavy work like downloading the files or uploading files into it, may cause the SSH timeout error. can anyone say weather this is correct or not